# Nearest neighbour

Tags: clustering, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a point with spatial and temporal coordinates

```
x=(lonx,latx,timex)
```

and I would like to find the nearest neighbour (according to some metric) amongst these other points

```
y1 = c(lony1,laty1,timey1)
y2 = c(lony2,laty2,timey2)
...
yn = c(lonyn,latyn,timeyn)
```

Is there any nearest-neighbour algorithm that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to calculate the time when you can reach your neighbour's place and compare that time with its time. The only parameter is the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Any metric index will work if you provide the metric.